# How to get the index in the upload file list in DropzoneJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, upload, dropzone.js

I am practicing dropzoneJS and I wanna know how to get the index of a certain file in the list because I want to delete an element of an array related to the file I uploaded.

I made an array called `uploadedImages`.

```
var uploadedImages = []; //I somehow made it to store the image array from database
```

I want to store to `uploadImages` the file names on `addedfile` function

```
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
    uploadedImages.push(file.name);

});
```

Then filter out the images from `uploadedImages` the files removed but I did it with the `file.name` of Dropzone but what if I have plenty of images with the same name or somehow I uploaded the same file multiple times. I think the better way is to find the index.

```
myDropzone.on("removedfile", function(file) {
 var filterUpload = uploadedImages.filter(function(img_file){
     return img_file != file.name;
  });
  uploadedImages = filterUpload;
});
```

Any suggestions please.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: You should answer your question if you found any solution later.
I'm facing the similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Server Side**

After successfull validation & upload at server side, store image info in the database. Then get imageID (last inserted ID in DB table) and store it in $_SESSION array:

```
$_SESSION["uploadedImages"][$imageID] = fileName;
```

At the end of the PHP code output a json response with File ID:

```
$out = array("fileID"=>$imageID);
echo json_encode($out);
```

**Client Side**

Use that file ID in Dropzone callback and store it in the File object like the following:

```
dropZone.on("success", function(file, response){
    obj = JSON.parse(response);
    //Save file id returned from server:
    file.id = obj.fileID;
});
```

Now when removing a file, send the stored fileID to the server:

```
dropZone.on("removedfile", function(file){
     //Delete uploaded file from server:
     var imageID = file.id;
     $.post("upload.php","deleteImage="+imageID, function(data){    
          alert("removed")
     });
});
```

then simply in upload.php use the ID to delete the image from database and from $_SESSION array.

Answer (score 1):

This partially answers your question. It will get the index from the array of files that Dropzone currently has.

```
myDropzone.on("removedfile", function(file) {    
    // get index of dropzone file
    var index = myDropzone.files.map(function (obj, index) {
        if (file == obj) {
            return index;
        }
    }).filter(isFinite)[0];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make a variable storing files and get the index on removedfile callback like the following:

```
success: function(file, response) {
            dz_uploaded_url.push(file);
        },
        removedfile: function(file) {
            var index = dz_uploaded_url.map(function(d, index) {
                if(d == file) return index;
            }).filter(isFinite)[0];

            var _ref;
            return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0; 
        }
```